# Somando dados de uma mesma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

Existe algum jeito de fazer um cálculo(soma) usando valores da mesma coluna?

Por exemplo: o cliente quer comprar uma cota no valor de 2000, no banco eu tenho várias cotas cadastradas, entre elas uma no valor de 1000, outra no valor de 600 e uma terceira no valor de 400.

> ```
> id      valor        admin
> 200     400          bb
> 333     500          caixa
> 356     1000         bb
> 567     600          bb
> 788     350          bb
> 900     200          caixa
> ```

Em tentativas, achei o número mais próximo de forma direta, através de um campo (não da somatória de campos). exemplo:

```
select * from produtcs order by ABS(value - 2000)
```

Comment: select sum(valor) from produtcs Pela descrição do seu problema creio que isso resolva.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é necessário fazer na programação, mas se você realmente precisar fazer no MySql, uma saída seria montar uma `procedure` que calcule e retorne para você.
Montei uma bem simples que funciona para o caso mencionado na pergunta, mas precisa ser aprimorada para outros tratamentos, é basicamente uma luz do que pode ser feito:

**Criação da `PROCEDURE`**

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS selectCotas$$

CREATE PROCEDURE selectCotas(cota int(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE _id INT(11);
    DECLARE _valor INT(11);
    DECLARE restante INT(11) DEFAULT cota;
    DECLARE ids TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE fim TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT id, valor FROM cotas WHERE valor <= cota ORDER BY valor DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fim = 1;

    OPEN curs;

    REPEAT
        FETCH curs INTO _id, _valor;

        IF (fim = 0) THEN
            IF (_valor <= restante) THEN
                SET restante = restante - _valor;
                IF (ids = '') THEN
                    SET ids = _id;
                ELSE
                    SET ids = CONCAT(ids, ', ', _id);
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    UNTIL (fim or restante = 0) END REPEAT;

    CLOSE curs;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM cotas WHERE id IN (', ids, ')');
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

**Executando**

```
call selectCotas(2000);
```

**Retorno**

```
+----------------------------------+  
|   id   |   valor   |    admin    |  
|     200|        400|           bb|
|     356|       1000|           bb|
|     567|        600|           bb|
+----------------------------------+
```